# xhr.js:210 POST http://localhost:3000/api/users/login 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: reactjs, api, authentication, post, axios

Hello I am developing a login system and when I try to make a post request to localhost:5000/api/users login I get:

xhr.js:210          POST http://localhost:5000/api/users/login 401 (Unauthorized)

this is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { Form, Button, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./LoginScreen.css";
import axios from 'axios';



  function LoginScreen() {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const submitHandler = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      
      try {
        const config = {
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
          },
        };

        setLoading(true);
        

        const { data } = await axios.post(
          "http://localhost:5000/api/users/login",
          {
            email,
            password,
          },
          config);
        
        console.log(data);
        
        localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(data));

        setLoading(false);

      } catch (error) {
        setError(error.response.data.message);
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

      return (   
          <div className="login_outer">
              <h1>Login Here</h1>
       <div className="loginContainer">
            <Form onSubmit={ submitHandler }>
           <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail" >
             <Form.Label>E-mail: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control size="lg" type="email" value={email} placeholder="Enter Email" className="input" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
           </Form.Group>
           <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
             <Form.Label>Password: </Form.Label>
                <Form.Control size="lg" type="password" value={password} placeholder="Enter Password" className="input" onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
           </Form.Group>
           <Button  className="login_button" variant="primary" type="submit">
             Submit
           </Button>
         </Form>
         <Row className="py-3">
           <Col>
             New User ? <Link to="/register">Register Here</Link>
           </Col>
         </Row>
       </div>
    </div>
   );
 }

 export default LoginScreen;
```

Can anyone offer help with that ? I also have a proxy in the src folder. If I use postman for that request it does work.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your client-side code